# What can the comma symbol be used for on the CASIO fx-85ES PLUS scientific calculator?

Tags: calculator

Please note that this question may or may not be connected to this stack exchange. If it is not, please help me transfer it to the correct one.

Scientific calculators have always have that comma or momayyez symbol. Mine, a CASIO fx-85ES PLUS, have it located at SHIFT + ). And everytime I think I'm using it correctly, it says syntax error, and the cursor jumps to whatever is before it.

My question is, how is that symbol used in some mathematical formula input in scientific calculators?

I think I need to add an " equals to something " before the symbol. But i cannot find any "equals to" sign ina ny calculators. Whoch led me to believe, it's there used as a multiple variable setter (like x = 1, -2).

Comment: The decimal separator (usually dot or comma, depending on which country you are in) is definitely a mathematical symbol that you can use in mathematical formulas. But its implementation (mainly, whether it is dot or comma, and how it's interpreted) very much depends on the calculator ...

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is too general for us to help. We don't know what your calculator looks like, what you actually enter and what actually happens. Calculators in the English speaking world generally have a key with a dot on it to indicate that you have finished entering an integer and the decimal parts will follow. That dot is used to show results too. In other countries the dot is a comma. The calculator may or may not use that.

Comment: @apanpapan3: I hope you did not delete your answer because of my comment which was meant as a joke...

Comment: I'm sorry for being too broad.. I'm using a "CASIO fx-85ES PLUS" scientific calculator.. And no it doesn't seem to be used simply as a decimal point..  I tried inputing "5*(1,2,3)" and it said syntax error. I also tried "100,500 * 3,00" and still returned syntax error

Comment: I've voted to close because your real interest seems to lie in the syntax error returned by your calculator.  Asking about whether a comma can be used in mathematics is pretty broad; commas might be used to separate items in a list or in a vector.  But discussion of those uses will not clear up whatever you are trying to do with your calculator, and unless that can be tied to a mathematical task, questions about using the calculator are off-topic.

Comment: I am asking about how the comma on my calculator is being used. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Casio fx-85GT PLUS, the comma key (i.e. SHIFT + right parenthesis) can be used:

1. To convert between rectangular and polar cooordinates.
   For example:
   $$
   \text{Pol}\left(\sqrt{2}\color{red},\sqrt{2}\right) \\
   r=2,\theta=0.7853981 \\
   \text{Rec}\left(\sqrt{2}\color{red},\pi\div4\right) \\
   X=1,Y=1
   $$
2. To generate random integers, e.g. in the range $1$ to $6$:
   $$
   \text{RanInt#}(1\color{red},6)
   $$
   Then keep pressing the '=' key.
3. To calculate logarithms to an arbitrary base, such as:
   $$
   \log(2\color{red},16) \\
   4
   $$

These examples are in the booklet that came with the calculator. There may be other things you can do with it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! about the booklet, I never got any booklet with it. the seller said it was original and that it was not opened for them to inspect the contents. I guess I really am missing quite a lot of functions without it.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.studentcalculators.co.uk/acatalog/Scientific___Instructional_Calculators.html), the GT is an updated version of the ES. From [this](https://www.casio-intl.com/product/image/1425458788119/) image, differences seem minor. This [PDF](https://support.casio.com/pdf/004/fx-82ES_83ES.etc_Eng.pdf) is laid out differently from the booklet that came with my GT, but it makes it clear that the polar and rectangular coordinate transformations and the logarithm calculations work the same way. Oddly, RanInt seems not to be mentioned, but the button exists! Does it work for you?